# Copy blob from Azure Storage and Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-blob-storage

I've seen several articles and post on this subject, but most of it seems maybe outdated or maybe I have the wrong version.

This article seemed to be what I needed, but CopyBlobHelpers.CopyBlobAsync does NOT seem to be supported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-copying-existing-blob

I think what I need is simple:
Take a file/blob from an Azure Storage account and "copy" to Media Services as an Asset so that it could then be encoded.

thanks,
v.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the sample on github 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-dotnet-copy-blob-into-asset

and the article will also be updated tomorrow.

Let me know if you have issues with the code.

thank you,
Julia

Comment: Julia this example looks to be copying from Media Services to Media Services.
I'm struggling trying to copy a blob object from Cloud Storage to Media services converting to an Asset (then I'll fire off the encode job).
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Voss, if you look at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-dotnet-copy-blob-into-asset/blob/master/CopyBlobIntoAsset/Program.cs, you will find the CopyBlobsFromStorageAccountIntoAMSAccount method. It copies blobs from a storage account to an asset.

Comment: Julia thanks for the help. I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correct. I have a single storage account in Azure that is leveraged by the AMS account. So in EncodeAndUploadTOAzure the _destinationStorageAccount is causing an issue because that blob account does not exists in the AMS. Not sure if this makes any sense.

Comment: Voss, you mean you already has a container in the storage account that you associate with the Media Services account. There is no way to customize what blob container an asset associates with 
The only way is copying blobs from some container into a container that was created during asset creation

Comment: @Juliako - Thanks for this sample. The sample fails on line 80 with AAD COM exception. Wondering if there is anything special that need to be done to make this sample work? I posted another question about this issue on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540952/azure-app-cannot-connect-to-media-services-using-c-sharp